# in Java, is JsonArray pass_by_value or pass_by_reference?

Tags: arrays, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

in Java, is JsonArray pass_by_value or pass_by_reference?

I want to crate new JsonArray for each iteration. I can achieve this with different logic.
But I just wanted to know what is wrong with the below logic.
Based on my understanding, in java all object created with new are passed as reference.

```
JsonArray jarr= new JsonArray();

for(i=0 ; i<5; i++)
{
   func1(jarr);  // for each call to func1, I need to create new JsonArray.
   // after the call returns from func1, jarr is empty.

}

func1(JsonArray obj)
{
    obj= new JsonArray();

    JsonObject jo_properties = new JsonObject();
    jo_properties.addProperty("test_name", "test_value");

    obj.add(jo_properties);

    // until here I able see all the filled values in obj.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is a question of passing-and-returning-objects-in-java.

1. JsonArray jarr = new JsonArray();  -> here jarr is pointing to address1
2. func1(jarr);   -> reference of jarr passed to obj
3. func1(JsonArray obj)  -> with func1(jarr) call, now obj is also pointing to address1
4. obj = new JsonArray(); -> obj is now pointing to address2
5. obj is filled with some values -> here address2 is filled. address1 is still empty.
6. after return from funct1 -> jarr will be empty, as it is pointing to address1, which is not filled with any values.

**Solution**

obj= new JsonArray(); -> remove this line, so that obj will still point to address1.

With this, if obj is filled with values, address1 is filled.
As jarr is pointing to address1, after return from function, jarr will not be empty.

For more details check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-and-returning-objects-in-java/